# If $[M]\in H_n(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is a fundamental class for manifold $M$, is $i(M)\in H_n(M,\mathbb{C})$ a fundamental class wrt $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I wonder if $[M]\in H_n(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is a fundamental class for manifold $M$, is $i(M)\in H_n(M,\mathbb{C})$ a fundamental class wrt $\mathbb{C}$?

I.e. does the image of $[M]$ in $H_n(M,\mathbb{C})$ generate the complex homology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Whatever is your preferred definition of homology, the group $C_i(M,\mathbf Z)$ of whatever $i$-chains with integer coefficients generates the complex vector space $C_i(M,\mathbf C)$ of whatever $i$-chains with complex coefficients, for $i=n-1$ and $n$. In fact, in all cases that I know of, a $\mathbf Z$-basis of the former is a $\mathbf C$-basis of the latter. Moreover, the boundary map
$$
\partial_{\mathbf Z}^n\colon C_n(M,\mathbf Z)\rightarrow C_{n-1}(M,\mathbf Z)
$$
is the restriction of the the boundary map
$$
\partial_{\mathbf C}^n\colon C_n(M,\mathbf C)\rightarrow C_{n-1}(M,\mathbf C).
$$ It follows that a $\mathbf Z$-basis of the kernel of $\partial_{\mathbf Z}^n$ is a $\mathbf C$-basis of the complex vector space $\mathrm{ker}(\partial_{\mathbf C}^n)$. Since the fundamental class $[M]$ of $M$ is a $\mathbf Z$-basis of the former, $[M]$ is a $\mathbf C$-basis of the latter. This means that $[M]\in H_n(M,\mathbf C)$ is a fundamental class with $\mathbf C$ coefficients.